# Does a computer mouse store or transmit the ‘images’ it takes?

Tags: mouse, computer-architecture

Does a computer mouse temporarily store or send to a computer the images it takes when tracking its movements? Or does it just send updated coordinates to the computer and the images are temporary and overwritten with each movement?

I am asking to make sure any information like text under a mouse couldn’t be captured by it and retrieved from the mouse or connected computer.

Thanks!

Edit: does the mouse have RAM in the DSP or somewhere else that hold the previous Image data in to compare the next, which then does that get overwritten with the next image data to compute?

Comment: Re your edit, it depends entirely on the mouse and how it works. Mice with balls simply had two rollers which allowed it to work out direction and speed of rotation. Modern mice *might* use a monolithic "black box" system which has no visibility to the outside world of how it works, or they might have a processor and camera style system that has readable memory. How they work depends entirely on the manufacturer of the mouse set it up to work with whatever sensor module they got. The only thing that you as a user know is that the mouse says "that direction at this speed".

Comment: If you want to know more about the in depth details then your question is going to be heading off into the land of electronics which is off topic here. Precise details of how each mouse works will be something only the manufacturer knows and likely they'll simply refuse to tell you. I'd  recommend Google: https://www.google.com/search?&q=mouse+laser+module where the first link is about interfacing with a relatively cheap mouse optical module https://www.espruino.com/ADNS5050

Comment: What makes you think a mouse works in "images" at all?  Its job is to convey positional changes, not pictures. To do that it doesn't need to have a clue where it was half a second ago, only the relative movement between last tick & this tick. Your edit sounds even more paranoid than the original question. What are you hoping to discover? That the CIA are watching what type of wood your desk is made of??

Comment: @Tetsujin: An optical mouse does *determine* the positional change based on images, and I've read about more than one hack/project that repurposed mouse sensors as very-low-res scanners... (by wiring them to a custom controller, of course, not literally by reading the images via USB, but that doesn't change the point being made)

Comment: Citation or it didn't happen. This is turning into pure paranoia based on hearsay & DIY hack projects.

Comment: @Tetsujin: [Citation](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Avago%20PDFs/ADNS-2610.pdf). (Page 18, register 0x08.) This is supposed to be turning into figuring out *why* OP might be thinking so, instead of immediately writing them off as a conspiracy nut, and this site is supposed to be for answers more along the lines of "it can't happen because of X and Y", not "you're an idiot for even asking this". If optical mice use CCD sensors, is it unreasonable to think that there would be security issues associated with that (similar to webcam hacks, etc), and that people would *ask* about it?

Answer (score 4):

Mouse send to computer number of "ticks" for X and Y coordinates (related to mouse) for particular time. No picture or anything from your fantasies is involved.
And mouse work by getting impulses from sensor which "see" the change of contrast of the surface below.

Comment: The mouse doesn't store anything, but the computer can… like you can draw in photoshop etc. If you were really paranoid, you could imagine someone recording all that movement all day...